# Trying to use PHP in HTML?

Tags: php, html, apache, wampserver

I'm using Wamp server to code a website on my PC, I'm following a tutorial on W3Schools for `<form>` and data collection with PHP (the GET method) and even though I followed the tutorial the code doesn't work.

I researched it a little here but no one seems to be able to answer my problem.

```
<form action="welcome_get.php">
  <section class="contact bg-primary" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Abonnez vous par mail!</h2>
      <input type="email" id="email" size="50" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse e-mail"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="mail-submit">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Je m'abonne"></input>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

That is the HTML before I send the email address, and this is the simple page to GET the email:

```
<html>
<body>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Yet it doesn't work at all. Here is the tutorial i followed

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

### Update

I made a mistake. I was opening the FILE through my browser NOT accessing through Wampserver.

Now the issue is when I click on Submit button (that calls the 
`<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">`) it downloads the `welcome_get.php`.

Comment: You're missing the `name` attribute in your input element. Should add `<input type="email" name="email" ... >`

Comment: nope that didn't fix it :/

Comment: To help you out on your forms read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: define `it doesn't work at all`: do you get a white screen? Do you get page with errors?

Comment: all i see on the "welcome_get.php" is the 2nd code : 
<html>
<body>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Try to visit `http://yourdomain.com/welcome_get.php?email=whatever` is it working?

Comment: Yes and no, i mean it says the correct email address in the URL but it doesn't print in on the page ..... and i don't understand why

Comment: make sure your extension is .php not .html :D.

Comment: my file extension is welcome_get.php .... do you think it could have something to do with Wampserver not accepting PHP scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not set method POST or GET :

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
```

Comment: No that changed nothing :/ do you think it could have something to do with Wampserver ?

Comment: I do not think so. You can open debug chrome (press F12 ) or check file error.log, maybe it will show an error

Comment: And the <input> tag has no end tag. You should remove </input> tag

Comment: OH!! input your email is not set name,  <input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="50" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse e-mail">

Comment: i don't understand, this is the code right now 
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" size="50" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse e-mail">
sorry some of it is in french (not the useful parts luckily)

Comment: name:you can get value from input through name attribute ($GET['email] OR $_POST['email']), Id :you can set css,type:Specifies the type <input> element to display,placeholder:used to annotate

Comment: So i can basically take the ID off ? (which i just did)

Comment: No, you can not get value of id attributed and send to php file, php only get value of name attribute.

Comment: if you only have <input name="email" type="email" > then it still work fine

Comment: i just took the ID off but it doesn't change anything.... the email address is in the URL but it doesn't print on the page :/ and i don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

First :
add method GET

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
```

Second :
add attributte name in input

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="50" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse e-mail"></input>
```

Final :
make sure your extension is .php not .html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to your cache browser, what I advise you to use 
another browser to test your PHP script or try to clear your cache browser and then it should work.

Comment: did you try it?